# How do I have all Libreoffice windows open always on the primary monitor?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, window, 21.10

In a dual monitor setup, libreoffice windows are always opening in the second, that is external monitor.

Is there a way to force Libreoffice to always open all windows on the primary monitor?

Comment: There is ridiculously little control on window placement in Gnome - seems to be better in KDE. See https://superuser.com/a/1656561 It is worthy trying it out - you can easily undo.